# T-SQL different JOIN approaches, same results, which one would you prefer?

Tags: t-sql, left-join, inner-join, database-performance

these are 3 approaches how to make a join. I would like to hear some word on perforance of these 3 queries.
Thank you

```
SELECT * FROM 
tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B
    INNER JOIN tableC C
    ON C.ColumnC = B.ColumnB

ON B.ColumnB = A.ColumnB
WHERE ColumnX = 'XY'
```

---

### Versus

```
SELECT * FROM 
tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B 
    ON B.ColumnB = A.ColumnB
INNER JOIN tableC C
    ON C.ColumnC = B.ColumnB
WHERE ColumnX = 'XY'
```

---

### Versus Common Table Expression

```
WITH T...
```

Comment: Run them all with Actual Execution plan and investigate it. Its very hard to predict.

Comment: I did some testing with a few of my own tables.  The results seam to be very close for the first two.

Comment: Are you missing some parentheses in the first code block? The JOIN condition for tableB is after the INNER JOIN on tableC?

Comment: @NickyvV - this is perfectly valid T-SQL. What it means is, that an INNER JOIN between TableB and TableC is performed first. The resulting table is then LEFT JOIN'ed to TableA.

Comment: Personally, I keep my INNER JOIN at the top.  In this example, I would have a CTE with my left join.  Below that, I would do an inner join on  TableC.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter.

SQL Server has a cost-based optimizer (as opposed to a rule-based optimizer).  That means that the engine is able to figure out that both of your first two options are identical.  Run your estimated and actual execution plans and you will see that this is the case.

The only reason you would choose one option over the other is for readability's sake.  I go with your second option, because it's a lot easier to read when there are a great many joins involved.  ON clauses in reverse order become quite difficult to track.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, any of the above could be quicker depending on your tables.

As you're setting up joins, you want to start with the most restrictive as possible (without negatively affecting your end result, obviously). This same logic also applies to the Where clause for the same reason. By starting with the most restrictive, you're limiting the number of rows that are being joined and thus evaluated by the Where clause and then returned/manipulated in the select clause. For my answers below regarding the three specific scenarios, I'm assuming a sufficiently complicated query that is doing more than just looking to combine data from multiple tables (i.e., queries answering specific questions).

If Table A is huge and Tables B & C are smaller and more directly related to the data you're trying to isolate, then the first option would likely be fastest.

If Table B or C are huge and Table A is more related to your desired data, the second option would likely be fastest.

As far as option 3 goes, I love CTEs but I try to only use them when I *need* to do so. Using a CTE will speed up your overall query if the data joined, manipulated, and returned by the CTE is only related to the rest of the query in a limited fashion. Including tables that are only partially related to your end result in your primary string of joins is going to needlessly slow down your query. If you can parse out that data into a CTE, it can run quickly by itself and then be incorporated back into the main query at the end.

Comment: Hate to do this, but -1.  SQL Server has a cost-based optimizer.  It absolutely *does not* decide query plans based on the order of clauses in your T-SQL, though a different structure, such as using an EXISTS clause versus a JOIN, or a outer vs. inner join, will change the semantics and therefore the speed of execution.

Comment: So specifying whether the inner join vs outer join occurs first would not impact performance, but changing the inner join to an outer join or vice versa would? Honestly asking.

Comment: Often it does, but it depends on what the relationships are between the tables.  Since the semantics of the join are different (that is, since different rows could be returned), the performance and plans will often be different.